# conditional counting within/sum across and transformations

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, transformation

### Update at 2012-09-24 06:52:00Z

After [David Robinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712603/david-robinson) asked some really good questions I realized that my initial question wasn't accurate.

I'm thinking about my problem as a two step thing,

First I need to look thru my data to identify `id`s who only have the `time` `intake_arm_1` and create a new row with only their # in `id`, `v_001_arm_1` in `time`, and their # in `c_n`. To get the right match between their `t_name` and `c_name` I use the `lookup` table.

Second, I need to perform more or less the same precede within `id` on the 'v_001_arm_1' though `v_010_arm_1` if latest *arm* have any `ti_all` registered, count these instances by `ty_all`, and write those number to the columns `out_c` and `out_c`. Furthermore, I also have to transport the name number from `intake_arm_1` to this new row, again if the latest `ti_all` is not NA.

The # of the new *v_00n_arm_1* should be "the current highlight number" (e.g. `v_007_arm_1`) + 1 (e.g. `v_008_arm_1`).

I will work on manually making a compel example of what I am aiming for.

```
lookup <- structure(list(c_name = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), t_name = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Bob", "Julian", "Mitt", "Ricky", "Tom", "Victor"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("c_name", "t_name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
> lookup
  c_name t_name
1      1    Bob
2      2 Julian
3      4   Mitt
4      5  Ricky
5      6    Tom
6      7 Victor

mydata <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L), time = c("intake_arm_1", "v_001_arm_1", "intake_arm_1", "intake_arm_1", "intake_arm_1", "v_001_arm_1", "v_002_arm_1", "v_003_arm_1", "v_004_arm_1", "v_005_arm_1", "v_006_arm_1", "v_007_arm_1", "intake_arm_1", "v_001_arm_1", "intake_arm_1", "intake_arm_1", "v_011_arm_1", "v_012_arm_1", "v_013_arm_1", "intake_arm_1", "intake_arm_1"), dat_all = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2012-09-23", "2012-09-23", "2012-09-02", "2012-09-10", "2012-09-23", NA, NA, NA, NA, "2012-09-23", "2012-09-23", "2012-09-23", NA, NA), ti_all = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 44L, 33L, NA, 22L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65L, NA, 10L, NA, NA),     ty_all = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "out_", "out_", "cma_",     NA, "cma_", NA, NA, NA, NA, "out_", "out_", "out_", NA, NA), out_c = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), cma_c = c(NA, NA,     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,     NA, NA, NA, NA), c_n = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L,     4L, 7L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 7L, 7L, 7L, NA, NA), t_name = c("Tom",     NA, "Ricky", "Ricky", "Victor", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,     "Julian", NA, "Julian", "Bob", NA, NA, NA, "Mitt", "Mitt")), .Names = c("id", "time", "dat_all", "ti_all", "ty_all", "out_c", "cma_c", "c_n", "t_name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"))
> mydata    
     id          time    dat_all ti_all ty_all out_c cma_c  c_n  t_name
1     1  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA     Tom
2     1   v_001_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    1      NA
3     2  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA   Ricky
4     3  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA   Ricky
5     4  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA  Victor
6     4   v_001_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA      NA
7     4   v_002_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA      NA
8     4   v_003_arm_1 2012-09-23      6   out_    NA    NA    7      NA
9     4   v_004_arm_1 2012-09-23     44   out_    NA    NA    4      NA
10    4   v_005_arm_1 2012-09-02     33   cma_    NA    NA    7      NA
11    4   v_006_arm_1 2012-09-10     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA      NA
12    4   v_007_arm_1 2012-09-23     22   cma_    NA    NA    1      NA
13    5  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA  Julian
14    5   v_001_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    2      NA
15    6  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA  Julian
16    7  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA     Bob
17    7   v_011_arm_1 2012-09-23     65   out_    NA    NA    7      NA
18    7   v_012_arm_1 2012-09-23     NA   out_    NA    NA    7      NA
19    7   v_013_arm_1 2012-09-23     10   out_    NA    NA    7      NA
20    8  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA    Mitt
21    9  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA    Mitt
```

This is what I am aiming at (unless I have made a typo),

```
    id          time    dat_all ti_all ty_all out_c cma_c  c_n  t_name
1    1  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA     Tom
2    1   v_001_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    1      NA
3    2  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA   Ricky
4    2   v_001_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    5      NA
5    3  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA   Ricky
6    3   v_001_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    5      NA
7    4  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA  Victor
7    4   v_001_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA      NA
8    4   v_002_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA      NA
9    4   v_003_arm_1 2012-09-23      6   out_     1    NA    7      NA
10   4   v_004_arm_1 2012-09-23     44   out_     2    NA    4      NA
11   4   v_005_arm_1 2012-09-02     33   cma_     2     1    7      NA
12   4   v_006_arm_1 2012-09-10     NA     NA     2     1   NA      NA
13   4   v_007_arm_1 2012-09-23     22   cma_     2     2    1      NA
14   4   v_008_arm_1         NA     NA     NA     2     2    7      NA
15   5  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA  Julian
16   5   v_001_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    2      NA
17   6  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA  Julian
18   6   v_001_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    2      NA
19   7  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA     Bob
20   7   v_011_arm_1 2012-09-23     65   out_     1    NA    7      NA
21   7   v_012_arm_1 2012-09-23     NA   out_     1    NA    7      NA
22   7   v_013_arm_1 2012-09-23     10   out_     2    NA    7      NA
23   7   v_014_arm_1         NA     NA     NA     2    NA    1      NA
24   8  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA    Mitt
25   8   v_001_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    4      NA
26   9  intake_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA   NA    Mitt
27   9   v_001_arm_1         NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    4      NA
```

---

ps: I've seen people do amazing things with `aggregate` and `tapply`.

Comment: You haven't offered a bounty and can't offer one until some time has passed.

Comment: What do you mean by "do the same thing" with these rows? Do you mean that every ID will get exactly one new row?  Am I correct that row 11 is the one you added manually (for ID 4, as you say?) If so, why is it named `v_007_arm_1` and not `v_006_arm_1`?

Comment: @Maiasaura, I am aware of that. That is why I wrote it, but I intend to keep my word and award the bounty regardless. If I could offer the bounty now I would do it.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, Thank you for your question. By *the same thing* I mean that for `time` `v_001_arm_1` thru `v_010_arm_1` I need to identify the latest 'v_00n_arm_1' and if that arm have any time registered in `out_time` I need to add a row. Every ID will get exactly one new row if the last row have time registered. Yes, I added row 11 manually to illustrate *the second step*. Does that clarify it?

Comment: How did you come up with the name `v_007_arm_1` for row 11 (I would expect `v_006_arm_1`)?

Comment: @DavidRobinson, good question. There is different 'activities' stored on the `time` variable, so *v_00n_arm1* is not 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10. There can be *holes* in the numbering, so to speak.

Comment: I understand, but how can that be determined programatically? That is- how did you get the number 007 from the data?

Comment: @DavidRobinson, You are making me realize that I ought to use `out_date` to sort time when counting and writing into 'out_calc'. People in the front end of my system could register a patient outreach on `v_007_arm_1` and the later realize that they forgot to use 'v_003_arm_1' and the register an outreach there (I cannot change the front end)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17045/discussion-between-david-robinson-and-eric-fail)

Comment: @EricFail If you don't award the bounty manually to the answer, David Robinson will only get half the points!

Comment: @EricFail: Thanks for the bounty, it's much appreciated. Mostly I'm glad I could help! I hope you met your deadline.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using [plyr](http://plyr.had.co.nz/):

```
lookup <- structure(list(c_name = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), t_name = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Bob", "Julian", "Mitt", "Ricky", "Tom", "Victor"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("c_name", "t_name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

mydata <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L), time = c("intake_arm_1", "v_001_arm_1", "intake_arm_1", "intake_arm_1", "intake_arm_1", "v_001_arm_1", "v_002_arm_1", "v_003_arm_1", "v_004_arm_1", "v_005_arm_1", "v_006_arm_1", "v_007_arm_1", "intake_arm_1", "v_001_arm_1", "intake_arm_1", "intake_arm_1", "v_011_arm_1", "v_012_arm_1", "v_013_arm_1", "intake_arm_1", "intake_arm_1"), dat_all = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2012-09-23", "2012-09-23", "2012-09-02", "2012-09-10", "2012-09-23", NA, NA, NA, NA, "2012-09-23", "2012-09-23", "2012-09-23", NA, NA), ti_all = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 44L, 33L, NA, 22L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65L, NA, 10L, NA, NA),     ty_all = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "out_", "out_", "cma_",     NA, "cma_", NA, NA, NA, NA, "out_", "out_", "out_", NA, NA), out_c = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), cma_c = c(NA, NA,     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,     NA, NA, NA, NA), c_n = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L,     4L, 7L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 7L, 7L, 7L, NA, NA), t_name = c("Tom",     NA, "Ricky", "Ricky", "Victor", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,     "Julian", NA, "Julian", "Bob", NA, NA, NA, "Mitt", "Mitt")), .Names = c("id", "time", "dat_all", "ti_all", "ty_all", "out_c", "cma_c", "c_n", "t_name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"))

library(plyr)

newrows <- ddply(mydata, .(id), function(subdata) {
    subdata_ty = subdata[!is.na(subdata$ty_all), ]
    if (NROW(subdata) == 1) {
        r = subdata[1, ]
        c("v_001_arm_1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                    lookup$c_name[lookup$t_name == r$t_name], r$t_name)
    }
    else if (NROW(subdata_ty) > 0 & !is.na(subdata_ty[NROW(subdata_ty), ]$dat_all)) {
        numbers = sapply(strsplit(subdata$time, "_"), function(l)
            ifelse(l[1] != "intake", as.numeric(l[2]), 0))
        newname = paste(c("v", sprintf("%03d", max(numbers) + 1), "arm", "1"),
                            collapse="_")
        r1 = subdata[1, ]
        new_c_n = lookup$c_name[lookup$t_name == r1$t_name]

        new_out_c = sum(subdata$ty_all == "out_" & !is.na(subdata$ti_all))
        new_cma_c = sum(subdata$ty_all == "cma_" & !is.na(subdata$ti_all))

        # you want them to be NA instead of 0:
        new_out_c = ifelse(new_out_c == 0, NA, new_out_c)
        new_cma_c = ifelse(new_cma_c == 0, NA, new_cma_c)        

        return(c(newname, NA, NA, NA, new_out_c, new_cma_c, new_c_n, NA))
    }
})

# recombine and sort
colnames(newrows) = colnames(mydata)
newdata = rbind(mydata, newrows)
newdata = newdata[order(newdata$id), ]
```

Comment: It is really  close, I have one small bump I am trying to solve. If I keep looping over the data it keeps growing on rows where $ti_all is not NA. It works for the first part, line 2 dose not keep growing, it only get copied once.

Comment: I think the above fix will work. But why are you running the function on the data multiple times?

Comment: I am constantly looking at a server to see if new cases was added, and if that is the case I want to add the new lines, that is why I want to run the script several times. I can 'transfer' the reward in 23 hours.

Comment: @EricFail: Cool, that makes sense. Did the above fix work for you?